# Multiple devices looking for server with dynamic IP on local network. Ways to do it?

Tags: networking, dns, bonjour, service-discovery, mdns

I'm developing a system with a team of engineers whereby a number of embedded devices and a 'parent' device are all part of the same local network. All of them have their IPs dynamically assigned by the DHCP server of the network. The challenge is to find a way for the embedded devices (low resources) to locate the parent's IP and connect to it. After spending some time researching the subject, I found a couple of solutions, but all seem to involve adding mDNS support on the embedded devices. Due to resource constraints, we'd prefer to keep that as our last option.

Ideally, we'd like to do this by a simple standard DNS query, which is already supported in the embedded libraries we are using.

Thanks!

Comment: You could have the server subscribe to a multicast group, and send a query from the devices to that multicast group. Conversely, you could have the devices subscribe to the multicast group, and have the server look for the devices by sending a query to the multicast group. It just depends on how you need to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

> The challenge is to find a way for the embedded devices (low resources) to locate the parent's IP and connect to it.

Few thoughts:

1. A "well-known" custom MAC address on the parent device might help to discover it or communicate directly using this MAC.
2. Configure DHCP server to always lease the same IP to the parent device (using a well-known MAC).
3. Use multicast/broadcast to discover the parent device.
4. Use dynamic DNS to update parent device IP on the fly.